# Can one use PuTTy to check if an IP is static?

Tags: networking, putty, static-ip

I had a Comcast modem installed and it's supposed to be configured for a static IP. I'm trying to find a way to verify it is not set to get an address automatically via DHCP. I tried to do a `show run`, but I'm not seeing anything listed.

Can I do this with PuTTy?

Comment: A static IP address is provided by the service provider. You’re talking about Comcast. So, first you would require a business account, then you would have to purchase static IPs then the service provider would provision the static IPs with you or your technical contact on the phone and provide the static IP info to you. Your question would seem to indicate you don’t understand the process or purpose of obtaining a static IP address which should leave little doubt if you have one or not.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the make and model of your modem.

Comment: They had it set for a certain static IP address and a static IP address was billed. However, when I checked the configuration, the IP was a different address than what was provided in the information. When they had spoken to me over the phone (this is for an offsite location), they said they had issues with the discussed IP address. They did not update our team that there would be a new IP address. They have not updated anything to reflect this new IP address. I'm simply trying to find a way to verify that it is static. I was wondering if putty had a way to do this?

Comment: Unless Comcast tell you the IP address and it matches the one assigned to your router you can't tell if its static or not.  to find out your ISP assigned IP address, simply go to a site like whatismyip.com.   While I can use putty to get this information its not what putty is for or about, and is very much the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: You can find your IP with whatsmyip and do a reverse DNS lookup on it. If it resolves to an address with “static” in the name then it’s one of Comcast’s static IPs. However, you should be talking to the ISP about this, not guessing.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this with PuTTy?

PuTTY is a telnet and SSH client.  It lets you log into something running telnet or SSH, which is typically a shell of some sort, from where you can issue commands.

`show run` is a Cisco IOS (unrelated to Apple iOS) command that shows the current router (not modem) configuration on a Cisco platform.  If your modem is not a Cisco enterprise device you are really barking up the wrong tree.  (A similar command might work on some Netopia DSL modem/router combos but it's been a long time.)

You can indeed use PuTTY to log into a Cisco router's shell and issue that command.

If Comcast gave you a modem and not a router-modem combo, then the modem is not doing very much other than passing along what comes in on the cable line, and not running DHCP.

I don't know how the SMC branded devices with 4 ports work internally, though, which is what I've seen at a few companies that get business internet service from Comcast.

Anyway you're in over your head.  You should seek assistance from a networking professional with experience in dealing with Comcast.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, isn't that exactly what OP is doing?

Comment: Thank you Lawrence. Your explanation actually pointed me to where my brain was not able to click. I was in a slight state of panic to be honest. Our usual networking professional is on holiday, and so I was trying to pick up some of the slack. I was told that after the install, to verify the new IP address and make sure it was static. When I saw the IP was not the same as it was listed, I was honestly very lost on what to do. Now I'm able to see what my next steps should be. Thank you for being blunt and for your very clear answer.